# pywinauto testing with Windows paint

Tags: python, pywinauto

I am trying to play around with pywinauto and I thought one easy project would be to have it automate Windows paint. This turned out to be trickier than I expected.

I want to try to open the Properties menu item shown here:

[image: Properties menu item]

So far I have this code:

```
    from pywinauto.application import Application
import pywinauto

app = Application(backend='uia')

p = pywinauto.findwindows.find_element(title_re=".* - Paint")

app.connect(handle=p.handle)
dlg = app.window(title_re=".* - Paint")

dlg.File_tab.click()
```

That code connects to an existing open Paint window and opens the file tab. From there I am not sure how to actually click on 'Properties'. I thought something simple like "dlg.Properties.click()" might work, but that gives me an ElementNotFound error.

I found that the github page has some example code for Paint automation here:
https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/master/examples/mspaint.py

By looking at line 32 in the example I can see that they can access items on the menu by calling childwindow and invoking it. Line 32 in the github example says this:

```
dlg.child_window(title='Open', control_type='MenuItem', found_index=0).invoke()
```

I don't completely understand that. Is that saying that clicking on the file tab opens up a new "child window"? The other question I have is, what does invoking do vs clicking on something?

I tried to use the code from the github example but I am stll not sure how to get it to work. The github example runs the "Open" option from the file tab.

I tried to adapt the line from github and used "Properties" instead of "Open" like this:

```
dlg.child_window(title='Properties', control_type='MenuItem', found_index=0).invoke()
```

That actually causes Paint to crash when I try that.

The "Properties" menu item appears in the controls list when I print the control identifiers from pywinauto. It looks like this:

> MenuItem - 'Properties'    (L1, T476, R254, B531)
>   ['PropertiesMenuItem', 'MenuItem6', 'Properties']
>   child_window(title="Properties", control_type="MenuItem")

How can I use the information above to figure out how to properly access the menu item?

Answer (score 1):

I found that I was able to have pywinauto click on the "Properties" menu item with the following line:

```
dlg.child_window(title="Properties", control_type="MenuItem").invoke()
```

I still don't understand what the "invoke" is for as this does not seem to be described in any of the documentation.

Comment: `invoke` uses so called `InvokePattern` that represents a default action for the control. We decided to leave its name as `invoke` because it may have another meaning. We just use `click` method as an alias for button control only.